# How to Display Taxonomy image field on node page

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

I need to display Taxonomy term image field on the node display page instead of the term name.

Other fields are being printed like below and the $content variable is not printed any where. Any suggestions?

```
$policies = $node->field_policies['und'][0]['safe_value'];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your hook_preprocess_node load your taxonomy term and get the field image value

```
function hook_preprocess_node(&$variables) {   
   $term = $variables['elements']['#node']->get('your_field_taxonomy_term')->getValue();
   if (!empty($term)) {
    $terme = Term::load($term[0]['target_id']);
    $image = $terme->get('your_field_image')->getValue();
    $variables['image'] = $image; 
  }
 }
```

in yout twig file print the image variable.

hope this will help.